# Google Api, syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet, cron

Есть вот такой скрипт для генерации данных из гугл таблицы в xml для avito.

```
<?php
require_once "/var/www/rndsite/data/www/avito.rnd-site.ru/googleApi/vendor/autoload.php";


// Путь к файлу ключа сервисного аккаунта
$googleAccountKeyFilePath = '/var/www/rndsite/data/www/avito.rnd-site.ru/private/rewrite.json';
putenv( 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $googleAccountKeyFilePath );


// Документация https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

// Области, к которым будет доступ
// https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
$client->addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets' );

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets( $client );

// ID таблицы
$spreadsheetId = 'table_id';


$range = "list_name";
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();


$xbrl = '<Ads formatVersion="3" target="Avito.ru">';
for($i=1; $i<count($values); $i++){
   //формирование xml
}
$xbrl .= '</Ads>';


file_put_contents("avito-septik_los_ru.xml", str_replace('<br>','<br/>', $xbrl));

echo "XML софрмирован! ";
?>
```

Используется google api
Скрипт вызывается на сервере через крон
При вызове скрипта возникает такая ошибка :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/rndsite/data/www/avito.rnd-site.ru/googleApi/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 86
```

google api брала [тут](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases)

Comment: попробуйте поставить права 755 на файлы автозагрузки. Крон запускает скрипт под своим пользователем, есть подозрения что у php просто нт право на чтения файлов

Comment: Спасибо, но, к сожалению, не помогло :(

Comment: права проверили на всю папку vendor?

Comment: да, проверила, везде 755

Comment: Откройте этот файл и скопируйте её код в ваш вопрос. Предварительно - вы устанавливали Google API через Composer, или скачивали архив? Если второе - то это и есть ваша проблема.

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо огромное!!:)